# How do I modify xml internal attributes

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to edit a xml file.

```
XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
myXmlDocument.Load(@"C:\\Users\\Vahid\\Desktop\\HG\\HG\\HG\\singleM.kml");
XmlNode myNode = myXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(
    "/kml/Document/Placemark/Point/coordinates");
myNode.Value = coordinates;
myXmlDocument.Save(@"C:\\Users\\Vahid\\Desktop\\HG\\HG\\HG\\singleM.kml");
```

and this is my xml (.kml) file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"
    xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>change.kml</name>
    <Style id="sn_ylw-pushpin"></Style>
    <Placemark>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>0, 0,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
    <name>12</name>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: Do you have to use XmlDocument? You can absolutely get this to work with XmlDocument (the problem is in namespaces) but LINQ to XML is a more modern API.

Comment: any idea with my code?

Comment: Marc's code looks fine to me. But I'd still encourage you to use LINQ to XML if possible.

Comment: You don't need two ` \\ ` when you use the `@` symbol

Answer (score 0):

Xml namespaces:

```
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(myXmlDocument.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("kml", "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");
XmlNode myNode = myXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/kml:kml/kml:Document/kml:Placemark/kml:Point/kml:coordinates", ns);
myNode.InnerText = coordinates;
```

Note that there is nothing special about `"kml"` / `"kml:"` here - it could just as well be:

```
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(myXmlDocument.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("x", "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");
XmlNode myNode = myXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/x:kml/x:Document/x:Placemark/x:Point/x:coordinates", ns);
myNode.InnerText = coordinates;
```

The important point is that each of your elements are in the namespace `http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2`; the `AddNamespace` is just adding an *alias* for that, so that we can talk about the namespace conveniently - we then write the xpath using the alias, and pass the namespace-manager to the `SelectSingleNode` methods.

Comment: its not working my error is:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
In Line: myNode.Value = coordinates;
myNolde is NULL!

Comment: @VahidNazakTabar I checked it with the xml you posted... it worked fine; the node is definitely not `null`. Please check you have copied the line accurately.

Comment: @VahidNazakTabar note you *do* have to use `.InnerText`, not `.Value` - but that's about the only other change

Comment: thanks! its solved
this was the problem:
XmlNode myNode = myXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/kml/Document/Placemark/Point/coordinates");
right code is:
XmlNode myNode = myXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//kml/Document/Placemark/Point/coordinates");
thank you! :)

Comment: @Vahid the namespace approach was IMO far superior :(

Comment: its solved now, thanks for your time! :) as i said the problem was is "//kml" instead of "/kml" in my string. SOMETIMES TO SETS OF EYES ARE NEEDED :)

Comment: @VahidNazakTabar and again, let me explain: that is solving **the wrong problem**

Comment: i am confused! what is the RIGHT PROBLEM? i don't get it!

Comment: @VahidNazakTabar querying for the *correct namespaces*, rather than wildcard namespaces; but.. whatever